# Binding Asp.net MVC model data to a kendo TreeView template (local data)

Tags: c#, templates, kendo-ui, treeview

I am using a template to display my data in a kendo Treeview. Currently, the data is coming from Asp.net MVC model. I am new to kendo. I saw various kendo examples for binding to local data, but I am confused how to bind my local data inside a template in a kendo treeview.

I know this is a bit vague. Appreciate your prompt response.

Any simple example could help greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is basic example of ASP.NET MVC and Kendo UI. For more information see Telerik [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/treeview/overview)

**View**

```
<script id="TreeViewTemplate" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    <div>
        <span style="background-color: Pink">#: item.text #</span>
        <span style="background-color: yellow">#: item.id #</span>
        <span style="background-color: Green">#: item.expanded #</span>
    </div>
</script>


@(

     Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                 .Name("TreeViewTemplateBiding")
                 .TemplateId("TreeViewTemplate")
                 .BindTo((IEnumerable<NodeViewModel>)ViewBag.Tree, (NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
                            {
                                mappings.For<NodeViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, node) =>
                                {
                                    item.Id = node.Id.ToString();
                                    item.Text = node.Title;
                                    item.Expanded = node.Expanded;
                                })
                        .Children(node => node.Children));
                            })
)
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = new List<NodeViewModel>();

        var root = new NodeViewModel { Id = 1, Title = "Root" };
        items.Add(root);

        root.Children.Add(new NodeViewModel { Id = 2, Title = "One" });
        root.Children.Add(new NodeViewModel { Id = 3, Title = "Two" });

        this.ViewBag.Tree = items;

        return View();
    }
}

public class NodeViewModel
{
    public NodeViewModel()
    {
        this.Expanded = true;
        this.Children = new List<NodeViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Expanded { get; set; }

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return Children.Any(); }
    }

    public IList<NodeViewModel> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Feross.........Sorry for the delay. Your example really helped me to gain the basic understanding. I was able to do well in my previous project.